# How to set the RESUME variable to override these issues?

Tags: dual-boot, crash, 18.10

I have an Ubuntu 18.10 dual boot with Windows 10. I think that because of the error below my Ubuntu crashes/hangs a lot lately at the time of reboot/startup.

```
$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.18.0-15 linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 66.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 329 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic amd64 4.18.0-15.16 [13.4 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic amd64 4.18.0-15.16 [8,154 kB]                     
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic amd64 4.18.0-15.16 [32.7 MB]              
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 4.18.0.15.16 [1,868 B]                                      
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.18.0.15.16 [2,480 B]                                
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-15 all 4.18.0-15.16 [10.5 MB]                              
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic amd64 4.18.0-15.16 [1,195 kB]                   
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.18.0.15.16 [2,440 B]                              
Fetched 66.0 MB in 2min 25s (456 kB/s)                                                                                                           
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic.
(Reading database ... 197143 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../1-linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../2-linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-linux-generic_4.18.0.15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.18.0.15.16) over (4.18.0.14.15) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-linux-image-generic_4.18.0.15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.18.0.15.16) over (4.18.0.14.15) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.18.0-15.
Preparing to unpack .../5-linux-headers-4.18.0-15_4.18.0-15.16_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.18.0-15 (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../6-linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-linux-headers-generic_4.18.0.15.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.18.0.15.16) over (4.18.0.14.15) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.18.0-15 (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-14-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-14-generic
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
Setting up linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.18.0.15.16) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.18.0.15.16) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.18.0.15.16) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=09e25397-4a2c-4fb0-a605-a7013eecb59c)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-14-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-13-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Comment: reference: `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID`

Comment: I don't see any "issues".

Comment: `I:` is short for `Information:`, it's not an error, which would be `E:`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The swap UUID needs to be added to the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file.

The following command can show what your swap UUID is:

```
blkid | awk -F\" '/swap/ {print $2}'
```

You can run the following to set that in the RESUME file (it will be created if it doesn't exist in that folder):

```
printf "RESUME=UUID=$(blkid | awk -F\" '/swap/ {print $2}')\n" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Then run the following to update the kernels on the system:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Reboot the system so the changes can take affect.

This does last through kernel updates.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For now, i am going to "accept" this answer, because i don't know what i did and until next kernel update, I hope it doesn't give me same warning. (How can i know if this method really worked instead of waiting kernel update?) @Terrance

Comment: @PrabeshBhattarai This is what I have had to do to my machine too.  This happens when I install Ubuntu fresh on the system, but I allow it to pick the install, but I leave the old swap partition.  Well, the install creates a swap file and then I change back to the partition instead of the file and I get this message because the resume was never created by default.  This does last through kernel updates.  Maybe I should add this to the answer.

Comment: I don't have the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file already present, is that an issue? Or shall I make a new file and add `RESUME=...` in that file? I just started linux, so please pardon if this is a primitive question.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel The `printf` command above creates the file for you if it is not there.

Comment: LABEL and PARTUUID also can be used instead of UUID

Answer (score 7):

I will add just one caveat.

```
The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda2
I: (UUID=139d357c-829d-408d-bccc-147ec4402da8)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

The above was my case and the UUID stated there is the disk's (`sda2` in my case) UUID, *not* the PARTUUID (i.e. the partition's UUID where the swap is installed).

This is so counter-intuitive, as the warning suggests, at least to me, that the disk's UUID was the problem!

But long story short, here is my solution:

Add the disk's UUID to the resume file not the partition's PARTUUID.

```
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

In my case I added:

```
RESUME=UUID=139d357c-829d-408d-bccc-147ec4402da8
```

And if this is not clear, my `fstab` for my swap location is:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="139d357c-829d-408d-bccc-147ec4402da8" TYPE="swap"
PARTLABEL="HDD_Swap" PARTUUID="0067903b-aed0-48d1-8d59-956784616d48"
```

Comment: i'd come upon this error based on resizing my partitions/moving swap partition. in my case when running `mkswap` it returns a UUID and instructions i followed said to replace swap's UUID in /etc/fstab. using the same in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume as well resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use LVM (for swap too) on ubuntu server 20.04 and after installing updates I received the mentioned messages:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ... 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img->5.4.0-65->generic 
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2 
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubusrv--lv--swap) 
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I added `RESUME=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubusrv--lv--swap` to a file `resume` under `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d`.

update `initramfs` worked without any "I's" shown