# Error when running apt upgrade about initramfs attempting to resume from /dev/sda5

Tags: apt, swap, 19.04

I got this notification/error when I run `sudo apt upgrade`:

`I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5`
`I: (UUID=5d5f582e-29e1-4845-8345-94df4549ee75)`
`I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.`

I know that /dev/sda5 is my swap partition, which is 16 GiB in size. I have gotten this error before, but I have been getting it repeatedly in the past month. What is the "RESUME" variable it mentions and do I have to "set the RESUME variable" to fix this problem?
If anybody knows a solution, please share.
Thanks!

Comment: It's not an error, just an information (`I:`), how to override see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116778/how-to-set-the-resume-variable-to-override-these-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just information, as shown by the `I:`. It does not cause any problems for me and /dev/sda5 (my swap partition) continues to work fine.