# Where can the Classic Menu Indicator be found?

Tags: package-management, samba

"Classic Menu Editor" and "classic menu editor" are terms that Ubuntu does not understand.
On the other hand, type "sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator" in Mate Terminal and your wish will be granted.

I found and installed Samba, but then it disappeared. What I'm actually looking for is a way of transferring data over a crossover network cable.

The "system" killed this question as originally posted. Here's my re-write:

That's just a start. I'm a serious user of linux, accustomed to text menus and apps with names. Oddball icons are of no help. The Ubuntu Apps page is all icons and uncompleted names which Ubuntu won't let me sort by name; they're sorted by rankings instead.

I need the following app's: samba, and a text editor that doesn't line-wrap and which can handle long lists in the multi-megabyte range.

So far I've installed Ubuntu 20.4.2.0-amd64 from a live flash drive that I created from trisquel's Startup Disk Creator because the folder names in the ubuntu-20.4.2.0-amd64.iso look exactly like trisquel's .iso folder names; nothing else on the 'Net made sense.

Regarding Samba; Here is what Mate Terminal had to say about it:

```
sudo apt-get install samba 
... Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) 
... Checking smb.conf with testparm Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK. WARNING: The 'netbios name' is too long (max. 15 chars).
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Done Setting up samba (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) ... 
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service 
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services. (samba-ad-dc.service masked) 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nmbd.service → /lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service. 
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked. 
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: 
error: systemctl preset failed on 
samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smbd.service → 
/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service. 
samba-ad-dc.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it. 
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6) ... 
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ... 
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ... 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
```

Where is Samba; was it successfully installed ?

Regarding "Classic Menu Indicator" here's what Mate Terminal said:

```
sudo apt-get install 'Classic Menu Indicator' 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done E: Unable to locate package Classic Menu Indicator

Aside: same result for 'classic menu indicator'
```

I thought Wine might be handy; Mate Terminal responded:

```
sudo apt-get install wine ... 
Setting up libwine:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1) ... 
Setting up wine32:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1) ... 
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.5) ... 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-55-generic 
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb3 
I: (UUID=8c672cdb-7491-4701-9fb6-a071529c8cab) 
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Processing triggers for wine (5.0-3ubuntu1) ... 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ... 
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) ...
```

RESUME is a new function for me ... but /dev/sdb3 is a swap partition.

Continuing ... Whois installed with apt-get install OK. Likewise for nmap.

At one of two prior UBUNTU installation attempts, "Classic Menu Indicator" was listed in the icon-based UBUNTU software screen, but in the present installation ("Something Else" and "Normal") it isn't listed in a fashion that I can recognize. English has been my native language for 84 years.

Comment: Menu choices : Right click the (top) panel → Select "Add to Panel → → Usually there are three choices for Menu in MATE. ...... Samba file list `dpkg -L samba` ..... "setting up ...." indicates that a software package is installed.

Comment: As far as the RESUME goes, please see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1116795/231142

Comment: The Classic menu Indicator will help me navigate through the various stages of a script construction, which requires that several text editor windows be open at once, as well as several visits to the file manager and an occasional use of an internet browser and the Mate Terminal. Samba may help me make a backup of one HDD to another HDD on a different computer with a crossover network cable.

Answer (score 1):

For Classic Menu Indicator visit https://packages.ubuntu.com and you can find Classic Menu Indicator in [one click](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Classic%20Menu%20Indicator).

To install it use commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

About other questions:

- Samba is a SMB/CIFS file-server. You can check how it operates by navigating file-manager to `smb://localhost`
- You can check Wine installation by launch `winecfg`. But better and more-userfriendly method would be to install PlayOnLinux by

  ```
  sudo apt-get install playonlinux
  ```

  then launch it and install some Windows-oriented application using wizards.
- RESUME variable in grub.cfg is used to resume from hibernation, see this article [for ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation).

Next time please ask questions separately.