# s2disk: Could not use the resume device (try swapon -a). Reason: No such device when setting hibernation

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I am trying setup hibernation using s2disk while using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/892410/1112231) on ubuntu 20.04 but am facing an error when testing it as below.

```
username@PC-Name:~$ sudo s2disk
s2disk: Could not use the resume device (try swapon -a). Reason: No such device
```

When I do `swapon -s`

```
username@PC-Name:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p6                          partition   17942524    0   -2
```

and this is my disk
[image]

Comment: You have a swap partition. The instructions you're following are explicitly for **swapfile**.

Comment: Probably missing `RESUME=` for hibernating.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1116795/231142

Comment: running  `blkid | awk -F\" '/swap/ {print $2}'` give me `2241a457-d042-47f9-bce1-14d5c99246a9`

Comment: Read the rest of the linked answer and set the `RESUME=`.

Comment: I have, doesn't seem to fix the issue. @Terrance

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`?  If you also ran through all the steps in my linked answer here, did you reboot after setting the `RESUME=` variable?  I just did the steps outlined in the answer you linked and my answer of setting the `RESUME=` and `sudo s2disk` worked just fine for me.

Comment: @Terrance `RESUME=UUID=2241a457-d042-47f9-bce1-14d5c99246a9` this is the output, yer i did restart the PC and When I run `sudo s2disk` I still get the same error

Comment: Try one more command of `sudo s2disk -r /dev/nvme0n1p6`.  The error of No such device is very generic and doesn't say what device it is trying to access.

Comment: It is returning the same error @Terrance. Is it a problem with how I formatted my disk?

Comment: I guess there is always that possibility.  You can use `gparted` to create a new one.  But first you would have to turn off all swaps before deleting and recreating a new one `sudo swapoff -a`.  Then in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq in the area for creating a new swap partition is some good information.  You can skip the line of the adding the `RESUME=` to the Grub and only add it to the file.

Comment: Which seetings should I consider when formatting the disk?

Comment: Swap is swap, there is no format, but only a partition.