# Can't set Nvidia as default GPU, Ubuntu freeze on boot after installing Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, everything was fine until today I decided to change my NVIDIA driver, I changed it, I do not remember which one I was using.
Then I restarted my laptop and everything was almost ok. I opened the NVIDIA X Server settings and set the PRIME profile to NVIDIA (performance mode). Then I restarted my laptop. It freezes on startup, on the ASUS - Ubuntu screen, I use ctrl + alt + f3 keys and open the terminal, remove the NVIDIA drivers and restart. Now it works with Intel GPU, I installed nvidia-driver-510 and tried again to set my NVIDIA as default GPU, but the problem is still there. I cannot set my NVIDIA as the default GPU. Also, many options in NVIDIA X server settings are gone!!!!
Please help me! What did I do wrong?
My GPU is: `nVidia GP108M [GeForce MX250]`
And My CPU is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz`

This is `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command output:

```
─$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: Second VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX250]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Also when I installed it with apt, it gives me this message at the end:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-30-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p5
I: (UUID=f56ee4ed-58ac-49d4-a438-3ca75f08397a)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Comment: How did you install the drivers? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. Are you using X11 or Wayland?

Comment: I installed it with the Ubuntu additional drivers app, I also tried installing it with `apt` and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command. Each time I installed and removed it and installed with another method, but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you connect any PPA before you installed the driver? If yes, disable Secure Boot in BIOS. The driver is not used.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't add any repository and also secure boot is disabled

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe nvidia` output?

Comment: @Pilot6 Nothing. No output

Comment: It is a long story to debug. look into `dmesg | tail` and see what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136282/discussion-between-mohammad-mahdi-and-pilot6).

Comment: Before any further troubleshooting update UEFI.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The latest version of BIOS is installed on my laptop

Comment: To fix your resume message that you are getting see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116778/how-to-set-the-resume-variable-to-override-these-issues/1116795#1116795

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved my problem and I want to share it here so that it is a solution for those who face this problem in the future. First, you should remove all NVIDIA drivers and modules from your system.

```
sudo apt remove --purge *nvidia*
```

This command will remove all NVIDIA drivers and modules, as well as their configuration files.
Then, make sure you do not have any active repository other than the official Ubuntu repositories.
Download the official NVIDIA driver for Linux from the [NVIDIA website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/drivers/). Reboot your system and your system will use the Nouveau driver for rendering. Go to Additional Drivers and select the latest NVIDIA driver to install on your system. After installation, restart your system.
If you are not able to access the Gnome login screen, press ctrl + alt + f2, f3, f4, ... keys simultaneously to access the terminal. If that did not work, you should boot your system with nomodeset and then do the same. Enter your username and password and log in.
Your default Prime profile should be on-demand mode. You can view your Prime profile using the command below:

```
sudo prime-select query
```

Set your prime profile to nvidia

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then go to the path where the NVIDIA driver you downloaded from the NVIDIA website is located and install it using the command below:

```
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-***.run
```

Replace NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-***.run with the name of the file. Continue the installation process, and when asked if you want to install kernel modules, ... say yes. You will also be warned that your target Linux system has a custom driver installation that you can use instead of the official NVIDIA driver; ignore this message and install the driver.
After installation, reboot your system. Press Ctrl + Alt + F2 again to bring up the terminal and log in to your account. Go to the official NVIDIA driver file that you downloaded earlier. And uninstall it with this command:

```
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-***.run --uninstall
```

After uninstalling the driver, reboot your system.

Everything should be fine.  **DO NOT CHANGE THE PRIME PROFILE OR THE NVIDIA DRIVER VERSION OR EVERYTHING WILL GO WRONG AGAIN.**
As far as I know, the modules were somehow deleted in the kernel and when installing the driver from the official Ubuntu drivers, they are not installed. But the official NVIDIA driver we downloaded installs these modules and when we uninstall the official driver, these modules remain. Two drivers cannot be installed on the system at the same time, so we have to remove one.
If we remove the driver from Ubuntu drivers and keep the official NVIDIA driver, the problem will not be solved. I have tried it. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It's not supposed to work this way, but see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475091&p=14095895#post14095895 for some speculation on why this may be happening.

Comment: @ubfan1 I know this is not the best solution, but I don't want to mess with it right now, at least not on my main OS, I will probably install another Ubuntu on another part of my PC and test these things there. Because I have had problems with my graphics card on all three installations of Linux (once Kali and twice Ubuntu) and I don't think I can completely solve this problem. If I install the driver on a newly installed OS and the problem occurs again, I will report a bug to both NVIDIA and Ubuntu.

Comment: @ubfan1 And Thank you for your help and everything you did, I'm really grateful. I will read the forum speculation.